# Add share button to page app, and linking back to page tabx

Tags: facebook

I've created an application that is used as a page tab. I need to add a share button, like this the share buttons on this page: https://www.facebook.com/PixarMonstersUniversity/app_411774402198665

Is this possible to share a page tab (app) and have it link back to the page tab in Facebook?

I'm really not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.facebook.com/PixarMonstersUniversity/app_411774402198665

To create the share button of this app you just simple take the address of the tabbed app in your Facebook page and place this into the share button HTML.

An example of this is seen here:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="icon" share_url="YOUR_URL">
```

The above link will work to share the page's app. To share just the page remove the "/app_xx" and to share the app just place the app url.